# How to send label parameter from JSP to servlet?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets

I have a jQuery dialogue box which contains values as checkboxes. On selecting the checkboxes I am storing the selected values into label. Next I have to send these values from label as parameter through form to servlet but I don't know how to complete it.

Here is my code:

```
<form action="CallTimer" method="GET">
    <label class="button2">Set Date: </label>
    <input type="text" name="date" id="date" size="4">

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" id="Submit">

    <br/> 
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="departmentlink" class="button2">Select Reporting Level</a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <label class="button2" style="display:none" id="depart">&nbsp;Department</label> 
</form>
```

I am retrieving these parameters in my Servlet as:

```
String reportname=request.getParameter("depart");
System.out.println(reportname);
```

But it is returning null values. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand what gets passed on form submission and what is not. In a nutshell, only values of the input fields get sent to the server. You have several ways to solve your problem:

1. Write value to a hidden input field
2. Modify the query string (what gets sent after ? in your GET request)  during form submission (using java script):

   ?...&depart=xxx

Answer (score 3):

You have to use hidden input field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="depart" />
```